# How to check whether the .NET 6 runtime is installed

Tags: .net-core, wix

As part of installation of a WPF application using .NET 6 and a WiX installer, I would like to check whether the .NET 6 runtime is installed.

WiX provides pre-defined properties to check this for .NET framework but nothing for .NET Core and beyond so I am attempting to check for the presence of a registry key.

There is a registry key that can be checked under: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\sharedhost\Version

However, if I uninstall the runtime the registry key does not get removed, is there any other reliable way to check whether the runtime is installed, as well as which version is installed?

Answer (score 10):

**April 2023**

With the official release of WiX 4, it is now natively supported to check if the .NET runtime (core, desktop, or aspnet) is installed on the computer via the WiX 4 Netfx wixextension: https://wixtoolset.org/docs/schema/netfx/dotnetcompatibilitycheck/

Example usage:

```xml
<Fragment>
    <netfx:DotNetCompatibilityCheck Id="netCoreStatus" 
        Property="NETCORESTATUS" RollForward="latestMajor" 
        RuntimeType="core" Version="6.0.1" Platform="x64" />
    <Launch Condition="Installed OR NETCORESTATUS=&quot;0&quot;" 
        Message="[ProductName] requires Microsoft .NET Core - 6.0.1 or greater." />
</Fragment>
```

Internally, it uses the same packages I linked down below to run the NetCoreCheck executable.

---

**Original Answer**

WiX 3 currently doesn't handle this natively. It is being worked on for WiX v4 ([GitHub issue](https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/6264)). Reading the issue led me to these tools as a current workaround.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Tools.NETCoreCheck.x86
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Tools.NETCoreCheck.x64

You can use the files inside of these packages to check for a runtime. Either by running `NetCoreCheck.exe` directly or using the custom action DLL provided.

`NetCoreCheck.exe -h` to see help. But you'll want something like this:

```
netcorecheck --runtimename Microsoft.NetCore.App --runtimeversion 6.0.0
```

I don't know how to use the custom action dll but I do see it has two DLL exports.

```
 ordinal hint RVA      name

          1    0 00001500 CheckNETRuntime
          2    1 00002260 get_hostfxr_path
```

Comment: Thanks that looks very helpful but having tried it, I am getting the same issue as before when I was just checking the registry. It still reports that the runtime is there even after having uninstalled. I think the tool must be looking at the same registry key that I was checking.
However, the control panel no longer lists the runtime as installed so there must be some way of determining this.

Comment: I was not having the same issue. But I know this program does not check the registry.

In a sandbox, I ran the program to check if runtime was installed. It reported it was not. Installed 6.0.5 and rechecked. Exit code 0 (success). Uninstalled. Program returns non-zero exit code.

Answer (score 7):

You may use the Custom Action DLL mentioned in Hank's answer if you want to integrate this in your WiX project.

You can use the [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NET.Tools.NETCoreCheck.x64) package to obtain the dll.
Unfortunately there seems to be no documentation in existence for this DLL, so I used the [source code](https://github.com/dotnet/deployment-tools/blob/main/src/clickonce/native/projects/NetCoreCheck/CA/NetCoreCheckCA.cpp) to figure out how this works.

First you need to define a few properties that are used as input parameters for the .NET runtime check, and for the result of the check.

```
<Property Id="CheckNETRuntime_Framework" Value="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
<Property Id="CheckNETRuntime_Version" Value="6.0.0" />
<Property Id="CheckNETRuntime_Result" />
```

`CheckNETRuntime_Framework` is the framework to search for. There are currently 3 options:

- Microsoft.NETCore.App
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.App
- Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App

`CheckNETRuntime_Version` is the version of .NET to look for.
The result will be stored in `CheckNETRuntime_Result`. A value of `0` indicates the runtime was found, any other value indicates it was not found.

To run the custom action, do this:

```
<Binary Id="CustomActions" SourceFile="NetCoreCheckCA.dll" /> <!-- This should be the path to the dll -->

<CustomAction Id="CheckRuntime" Return="ignore" BinaryKey="CustomActions" DllEntry="CheckNETRuntime" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="CheckRuntime" Before="LaunchConditions"  />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
<InstallUISequence>
    <Custom Action="CheckRuntime" Before="LaunchConditions"  />
</InstallUISequence>
```

*Note: you need to add `Return="ignore"` if you do not want the installer to fail when the runtime was not found (as the return value if not 0, which indicates a failure).*

The `CheckNETRuntime_Result` property can be used elsewhere in your setup, for example you could use it in a condition:

```
<Condition Message=".NET 6 runtime is not installed">
    <![CDATA[CheckNETRuntime_Result=0]]>
</Condition>
```

Comment: Hi @chris , as per the answer given by you will it work in wix 3.x( I mean can we use the above answer in wix 3.x for detecting .net 6 )

Comment: Hi @AdityaDalai, yes it will. We are using WiX 3.x. I believe WiX 4.x has native support for detecting modern .NET runtimes. I have not really looked into that though.

Comment: HI @chris , currently I have Merge module(.msm) ,  setup.MyApp(.msi) and a setup.MyApp.Bootstrapper(.exe) so in which project I should define those properties ? do you have any sample code could you please provide me , Actually I am little new to this concept.

Comment: @AdityaDalai - The code above does work with products (*.msi). I have no experience with merge modules myself. AFAIK, you cannot run this from a bundle (.exe / bootstrapper). I have no further code samples for you unfortunately.

Comment: Hi @Chris, but while installing Microsoft.NET.Tools.NETCoreCheck.x64 nuget pack in my msi application it gives me error that Could not install package 'Microsoft.NET.Tools.NETCoreCheck.x64 6.0.0'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 'Unsupported,Version=v0.0', but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author. there is no TargetFramework in my msi application so can you suggest me where can I change so I can install this package

Comment: @AdityaDalai - When I worked on this, I think I also received that message. I'd added the nuget reference to our main project in the solution (regular C# project) to obtain the NuGet package.

Answer (score 7):

For Wix4 bundles, you need [DotNetCoreSearch](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/schema/netfx/dotnetcoresearch/) instead of [DotNetCompatibilityCheck](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/schema/netfx/dotnetcompatibilitycheck/). You use it like this:

```
<Wix ... xmlns:netfx="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/netfx">
  <Fragment>
    <netfx:DotNetCoreSearch Id="Dotnet6DesktopX86Version" Variable="Dotnet6DesktopX86Version"
      RuntimeType="desktop" Platform="x86" MajorVersion="6"/>
    <PackageGroup Id="Dotnet6DesktopX86Redist">
      <ExePackage DetectCondition="Dotnet6DesktopX86Version &gt;= v6.0.13"
      .../>
    </PackageGroup>
  </Fragment>
```

DotNetCoreSearch reads the current version of dotnet 6 desktop x86, and then DetectCondition is false if it is below 6.0.13 There is a more complete example in the wix source code [here](https://github.com/wixtoolset/wix/blob/v4.0.0/src/test/burn/TestData/TestBA/TestBAWixlib/NetCore6.0.9_x86.wxs).