# how to fetch the .net runtime version from a client machine using wix bootstarper?

Tags: c#, xml, wix, .net-6.0, wix3.11

my requirement is to check the latest .net runtime version in client machine so that i can compare weather the particular version is belong to .net 6 runtimes or not ,i have tried some few steps to achieve my requirement

```
<util:RegistrySearch Id="DotNetVersionSearch" Variable="DOTNETVERSION"
                     Root="HKLM"
                     Key="SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\dotnet\Setup\InstalledVersions\x64\sharedfx\Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App"
                     Value="Version"
                     Result="value" />
```

the paricular variable I have declared on top of fragement `<Property Id="DOTNETVERSION" Secure="yes" />`

and I have define one custom action to verify weather the .net runtime version is belong to .net 6 or not like below .

```
 <CustomAction  Id="CheckDotNetVersion"
                BinaryKey="CustomActionBinary"
                DllEntry="CheckDotNetVersion"
                Execute="immediate"
                Return="check" />
```

and the action i have defined in a class named as `Customaction.cs`

```
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult CheckDotNetVersion(Session session)
    {
        string dotNetVersion = session["DotNetVersion"];
        string dotNetVersionMin = session["DotNetVersionMin"];

        Version version;
        Version versionMin;

        if (!Version.TryParse(dotNetVersion, out version))
        {
            session.Log("Failed to parse DotNetVersion.");
            return ActionResult.Failure;
        }

        if (!Version.TryParse(dotNetVersionMin, out versionMin))
        {
            session.Log("Failed to parse DotNetVersionMin.");
            return ActionResult.Failure;
        }

        int result = version.CompareTo(versionMin);

        session["WIX_DOTNET_VERSION_COMPARE"] = result.ToString();

        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
```

and for displaying the error I have used the bal:Condition tag like below

```
<bal:Condition
        Message="This setup requires Microsoft .NET 6.0 or above."
        ><![CDATA[Installed OR (NOT Installed AND WIX_DOTNET_VERSION_COMPARE >= 0)]]>
    </bal:Condition>
```

but this is not working , can somebody help me on this to fix the issue

Answer (score 3):

Wix has a built-in support for .NET version check, you can use that:

https://wixtoolset.org/docs/tools/wixext/dotnet/#net-and-net-core

Wix 3.x does not seem to support .NET 6 detection out of the box (but I am not completely sure), but Wix 4 does, so you may need to upgrade.

To figure out what is not working with your code, you can run your installer with a log file (`msiexec yourfile.msi /l*v log.txt`), and check the values of your variables passed around in the log after run.

Other than that, not quite sure why you are using `<bal:Condition>`, it is for "bal", the bootstrapper (a program that runs before your installation starts). Custom actions are executed during the installation, not in a bootstrapper. So, there is no chance for this condition to work, as far as I can see?

Comment: HI @Nikolay, could you please suggest any way for detecting a .net 6 version of client machine using the wix 3.x(and is it possible to check the client .net 6 version in bootstrapper without  using of this custom action) , because  WiX 4 is not fully backward compatible with WiX 3.x so it difficult to predict all the custom action of my current setup will work there or not

Comment: It looks like there is a similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72518411/how-to-check-whether-the-net-6-runtime-is-installed. They recommend either use Wix4 directly, or use the method that is used by Wix4 (use the NetCoreCheck.exe)

Comment: Hi @Nikolay , i went through the link that you suggested , so as per the link its good to port the wix v3.11 into wix v4 so could you please guide me how to port it , i mean the initial steps , which wix.exe to install and which visual studio extension to use or and tool is available to port it immediately ,

Comment: There is automatic conversion tool I guess? https://wixtoolset.org/docs/fourthree/

Comment: Hello @Nikolay , thank for the suggestion i am able to use the convert command , but after converting it to wix v4 while building I am getting the below error          error CNDL0199: The Wix element has an incorrect namespace of 'http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs'.  Please make the Wix element look like the following: <Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">. i have followed this link  https://github.com/wixtoolset/issues/issues/5967 but couldn't get a satisficed answer , could you please help me on this

Comment: Did you use VisualStudio wizard to convert (v4 VS extension is called HeatWave, https://www.firegiant.com/wix/heatwave/)? It's easier and converts all project files. For me it worked fine. Note that you need to convert not only the project, but all .wxs files in the project

Comment: hi Nikolay , thanks for suggesting the tool its very easy to port , I have ported al the wix project in my application ,but during build i got this below error".nuget\packages\wixtoolset.sdk\4.0.1\tools\wix.targets(256,5): error MSB4062: The "UpdateProjectReferenceMetadata" task could not be loaded from the assembly "\packages\WiX.Toolset.UnofficialFork.3.11.2\tools\wix\WixTasks.dll" Confirm that the <UsingTask> declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask."please help

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this one, sorry... I woudl try to create another question with that.

Comment: Hi @Nikolay , I have verified the above error is coming because WiX.Toolset.UnofficialFork.3.11.2 doesn't support in wix v4 due to version miss match in the version and people suggesting WiX Toolset  is alternation for it but which version to use ,that I could not find , can you please suggest me which is the alternate package for WiX.Toolset.UnofficialFork.3.11.2 and  from where can i get  ?

Comment: I am not quite sure, what is "Wix.Toolset.UnofficialFork". Wix4 is available as nuget package, so you probably don't need that package anymore (and can remove the reference to it)?